# Randomly insert NA's values in a pandas dataframe - with no rows completely missing

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

How can I randomly make some values missing in a panda dataframe, as in [Randomly insert NA's values in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059032/randomly-insert-nas-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe) *but* make sure no row is set completely with missing values?

**Edit:** Sorry for not stating this explicitly again (it was in the question I referenced though): I need to be able to specify how much percentage, for example 10%, of the *cells* is supposed to be `NaN` (or rather, as close to 10% as can be achieved with the existing data frame's size), as opposed to, say, clearing cells independently with a marginal per-cell probability of 10%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer based on [Randomly insert NA's values in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059032/randomly-insert-nas-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe):

```
replaced = collections.defaultdict(set)
ix = [(row, col) for row in range(df.shape[0]) for col in range(df.shape[1])]
random.shuffle(ix)
to_replace = int(round(.1*len(ix)))
for row, col in ix:
    if len(replaced[row]) < df.shape[1] - 1:
        df.iloc[row, col] = np.nan
        to_replace -= 1
        replaced[row].add(col)
        if to_replace == 0:
            break
```

The shuffle operation will cause random order to the indexes and the if clause will avoid replacing the entire row.

Comment: Seems to work as expected. Is it also that 10% of the cells are NaN, and *not* that the probability of replacement is 10%? Can you explain how it works. I am not quite sure.

Comment: First it creates all the combinations of indexes. Then it shuffle the indexes randomly. Finally it iterates over the shuffled indexes and inserts NaNs until the number of required NaNs is achieved (to_replace = int(round(.1*len(ix)))). Before any replacement, there is a validation that the row is not full of NaNs.

If you want to change the percentage, replace the .1 with another value (for example, 0.5 for 50%).

Comment: And if the row is full of NaNs, the algorithm takes one more of the shuffled indexes than it would have otherwise?

Comment: It counts only the actual replacements so the final amount of replacements would always be the expected number.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and for `numpy boolean mask` is used [answer of this my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42092335/2901002):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

np.random.seed(100)
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape)
print (mask)
[[ True  True False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True]] -> problematic values - all True

mask[mask.all(1),-1] = 0
print (mask)
[[ True  True False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True False]]

print (df.mask(mask))
     A    B  C
0  NaN  NaN  7
1  2.0  5.0  8
2  NaN  NaN  9
```

Comment: Interesting idea. However there are three issues with that: 1) the last column gets more than average many non-NaNs, 2) just turning some element False, is distorting the percentage of NaN's, 3) for now I don't see how to set the percentage to e.g. 10%.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know about percentage. But maybe need `mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape, p=[0.1,0.9])` and then it will be very large dataframe for all `True` values in one row. Then my answer can be used for `100%` not all `True`.

Answer (score 1):

How about applying a function that will replace random columns' values. To avoid replacing the entire row it is possible to draw a number between 0 and n-1 of values to replace.

```
import random

def add_random_na(row):
    vals = row.values
    for _ in range(random.randint(0,len(vals)-2)):
        i = random.randint(0,len(vals)-1)
        vals[i] = np.nan
    return vals

df = df.apply(add_random_na,axis=1)
```

Comment: Is this making sure that the right percentage of cells is deleted?

Comment: No. I didn't see there is a requirement for exact number of replacements.

Comment: It was in the question I referenced. I stated it explicitly in my question as well now. Sorry for not making it clear from the start.

Comment: I added another answer which satisfy the requirement.