# Boolean array with no all True values in one row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, mask

I have `numpy array`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=(10,3))
print (mask)
[[ True  True False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True] <- problem - all values True
 [ True  True False]
 [ True  True  True] <- problem - all values True
 [ True False  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True  True]
 [ True False False]
 [False  True  True]]
```

Need in each row no all values `True` - so here can be only `0`, `1` or `2` `True` because  `3 'columns'`.

Ugly solution is:

```
mask[:, -1] = False
print (mask)
[[ True  True False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True False]
 [ True  True False]
 [ True  True False]
 [ True False False]
 [ True False False]
 [False  True False]
 [ True False False]
 [False  True False]]
```

What is better and more generic solution?

Comment: `mask[mask.all(1),-1] = 0`? That would create a different one than the one posted with the ugly solution though.

Comment: @Divakar your shorter code version beat my answer by a good few seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
In [109]:
mask[mask.all(axis=1),-1] = False
mask

Out[109]:
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

So just test row-wise using `all` and only set the 3rd col to `False` on this condition

Thanks to @Divakar, you could type less:

```
In [110]:
mask[mask.all(1),2] = 0
mask

Out[110]:
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

So here the position arg `axis` is being set and `0` is being cast to boolean `False` otherwise is same

Some explanation, first use `all` with `axis=1` to test row-wise if all are True.

Then we use that mask to mask the rows in the square brackets, the second arg `-1` selects the last column and finally we assign the new desired value

Comment: I would encourage you to add that shorter one as both are basically the same thing, if you would like :)

Comment: @Divakar sure will do

Comment: @dabadaba I'm using the original array as a mask, we test if all values are `True` row-wise when we pass `axis=1`, the `-1` sets the last column to the desired value

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fair one (all legal triplets equally likely):

```
N = 10
bits = np.random.randint(7, size=(N,))
mask = (bits[:, None] & 2**np.arange(3)).astype(bool)
```