# How to put NaN in Pandas Dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I have a `df` which contains of categorical and numerical data

```
df = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 
       'Address':['Oxford', 'Cambridge', 'Xianjiang', 'Wuhan'], 
       'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18], 
       'Weight':[50, 61, 69, 78]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I need to replace 50 % in each column to NaN randomly, so the result might look like this picture

[image]

how to do that with the most efficient techique because I have large number of rows and columns, and I'll do many repetitions.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059032/randomly-insert-nas-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: What is number rows and columns in real data?

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` with [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html)

```
df_final =  df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5)).reindex(df.index)

Out[175]:
    Name    Address   Age  Weight
0    Tom        NaN   NaN    50.0
1    NaN        NaN   NaN    61.0
2  krish  Xianjiang  19.0     NaN
3    NaN      Wuhan  18.0     NaN
```

Comment: The way it is written, it is getting 50% of each row, and not 50% of each column

Comment: @ibarrond: if it is 50% of each row, the expected output of row# 0 must have 2 `NaN`. OP expected output or row# 0 has only 1 `NaN`

Comment: @ibarrond: OP clearly says `replace 50 % in each column to NaN`. Do I misread something in the question?

Comment: You're right! however, when all 4 values are set to `NaN`, the row is filtered out (try with a bigger `df`  to see the effect or run your example multiple times).

Comment: @ibarrond: ah, you are right! It needs `reindex` to handle in case of the random of each column happened to same row. I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Improving three times the performance of previous answers, mostly inspired on @jezrael , I suggest using `argpartition` instead of `argsort`, since the sorting performed is rather useless:

```
df1 = df.mask(np.random.rand(*df.shape).argpartition(0, axis=0) >= df.shape[0] // 2)
print(df1)
   Name    Address   Age  Weight
0   NaN     Oxford   NaN    50.0
1  nick  Cambridge  21.0    61.0
2   NaN        NaN   NaN     NaN
3  jack        NaN  18.0     NaN
```

### Performance comparison

```
# Reusing the same comparison dataset
df = pd.concat([df] * 50000, ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([df] * 50, ignore_index=True, axis=1)


# @Andy's answer, using apply and sample
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5)).reindex(df.index)
9.72 s ± 532 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# @jezrael's answer, based on mask, np random and argsort
%timeit df.mask(np.random.rand(*df.shape).argsort(axis=0) >= df.shape[0] // 2)
8.23 s ± 732 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# This answer, based on mask, np random and argpartition
%timeit df.mask(np.random.rand(*df.shape).argpartition(0, axis=0) >= df.shape[0] // 2)
2.54 s ± 98.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: What is reason for such difference?

Comment: `argsort` is taking all the random values generated with `np.random.rand`, sorting them and setting an index for each. Instead, `argpartition` is just assigning index based on the partition info provided, which avoids sorting the entire array. You clearly don't need to sort all the random values to get the first half, just get the median value and generate partitions based on this median value. This is what, under the hood, `argpartition` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by taking random numbers in the range of your tuples and run a loop over them and consider that as index to replace with NaaN

example:
if you have 10 tuples
from random number generator set range to 0 to 9 and 
and take result of above operation as index to replace with NaN